# Use ServiceController to start a service with a different account

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm using the `ServiceController` class to start a (custom) installed service, like this:

```
var newServiceController = new ServiceController("theNameOfMyService");
newServiceController.Start();
```

Trouble is, the service always runs under the local system account, and instead I want it to run under my account.

Can anyone tell me how to use `ServiceController` to run a service under a different account?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can... the credentials for the service are provided at install time or alternatively via the Service.msc snap in

The service controller can only start/stop a pre-installed service

Answer (score 0):

On the ServiceProcessInstaller instance for you service there is a property called Acount, Password and Username, can use these properties to set who the service runs as.